# httpResponse/httppost Connection Refused Warning and then error due to it

Tags: android, xml-parsing, http-post

I am getting this warning :

```
    06-26 15:19:09.689: W/System.err(611): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
06-26 15:19:09.689: W/System.err(611):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
06-26 15:19:09.719: W/System.err(611):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-26 15:19:09.719: W/System.err(611):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-26 15:19:09.719: W/System.err(611):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-26 15:19:09.739: W/System.err(611):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-26 15:19:09.739: W/System.err(611):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-26 15:19:09.739: W/System.err(611):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

while trying to excute this code in a non-ui class :

```
1    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) { 
2            String xml = null; 
3            try { 
4                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
5                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 
6                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
7                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
8                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
9            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
10                e.printStackTrace(); 
11            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
12               e.printStackTrace(); 
13            } catch (IOException e) { 
14                e.printStackTrace(); 
15            } 
16            return xml; 
17        }
```

i am supplying url as

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/Mysite/xxx
```

What is the problem here.Why am i getting this error.

because of this the "xml" string is returned null which further leads to error in my app.

I debugged my app and i can see that i catch an exception IOException and because of this i am going from line 6 to line 13.

Comment: Are you sure that the adress is correct? Are you running the code in a new thread (recent versions of Android do not allow network operations on the main thread)? putting the code in a separate class is not enough?
Do you have the `Internet`-permission for your app?

Comment: yup address is correct , internet permission is there in manifest,
and i can run network operation on non-ui class in any of its thread(s) !!